# Rename a file the name of the directory that it is in

Tags: batch-file, rename

I think it's a simple task, but I'm a noob to batch scripting.

Here is what the structure looks like:

```
MAINDIR
    directory name
        nameof.file
```

I'm looking to batch rename all the files in the directories the same name as the directory.

Basically it is:

Scan the subfolders and find all `*.file`.

Rename the `*.file` to the name of the directory it is already in

The end result is `nameof.file` to be `directory name.file`

To be more specific, I have 350 files that i need to rename. They are all in their appropriate directory and I want the 1 file inside each folder to have the name of the folder as the file name.

```
c:\folder 1\file1.ext
c:\folder 2\file2.ext
c:\folder 3\file3.ext
```

All the `.ext` files need to have their folder names as file name.

```
c:\folder 1\folder 1.ext
c:\folder 2\folder 2.ext
c:\folder 3\folder 3.ext
```

I hope that makes it more clear. So once the script is prepared, I can drag and drop all 350 files and one by one onto the script and it will take the file and rename it.

Comment: What behavior you want to have if you have multiple files with the same extension inside the directory?

Comment: the files are all the same, they all have the same extension, there is only 1 file per directory. if it helps in writing the script, the files are .wad extension. so if the directory is : "Whatever_This_Name_Is", the file inside is NOW: FILE.wad, the scripted end result is Whatever_This_Name_Is.wad

Answer (score 0):

This will rename any file that is dragged onto it to it's parent directory name.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%a in (%1) do (
set p=%%~dpa
set p=!p:~0,-1!
for %%b in ("!p!") do ren %%a "%%~nb.*"
)
```

To do this recursively through all files in all subfolders under a fixed root directory you can use this

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /r C:\folder %%a in (*) do (
set p=%%~dpa
set p=!p:~0,-1!
for %%b in ("!p!") do ren "%%a" "%%~nb.*"
)
```

Which will save you having to drag and drop them all individually. Unless you can only do it one at a time, in which case the first solution will suffice.

Comment: thanks for the response, but i need it to take a drag-n-dropped file. i have about 350 files that need this done. that would do just the file it points to.

Comment: Oh right, I see what you mean, I will try and think of something :)